# Checking if a string matches "END", and exit if it does

Tags: c++, exit, palindrome

I have the following code below:

```
int main ()
    {
    char string[80];
    bool Restart;

Restart = true;

while (Restart)
    {
    cout << "Enter a string\n" << endl;
    cin.getline(string, 80);
    cout << "\nYou entered: ";
    printf(string, 80);
    cout << endl;

    int len=strlen(string);

    bool flag = true;

    for (int c=0; c!=len/2; c++)
        {
        if (flag)
            {
            if(string[c] != string[len-c-1])
                {
                flag = false;
                }
            }
            else
                {
                break;
                }
            }

if (flag)
    {
    cout <<"\nThis is a Palindrome\n" << endl;
    Restart = true;
    continue;
    }
else 
    {
    cout << "\nThis is not a palindrome\n" << endl;
    Restart = true;
    continue;
    }
cin.get();

    }
    }
```

I need to figure out a way to check if what the user entered is "END" in all caps, and if so, exit the program. I'm sure i can handle the exiting part, but I'm having trouble getting something that will check if the string entered is "END" in all caps.

Comment: Why not use std::string?

Comment: Because std:: is not needed and is a waste of typing :P

Comment: @Prstorero it's ok to say it's homework....but your indentation is sinful :P

Comment: I didn't think there was a need to say it was, but yes it is. Even so, I'm not looking for someone to give me everything i need. I want to understand how it works so I'm looking for assistance, not someone to just copy :) and I'm not worries about indentation until i get it to function properly. No sense in worrying about it now :P

Comment: `std::string` isn't the same as `char string[80];` without the `std::`.

Comment: I applaud that attitude. If you *must* use C style character arrays, and not C++ style `std::string`, then how about the C style `strcmp`?

Comment: I was told using std:: was not needed and was just unnecessary typing for everything we've done.

Comment: It seems, that using `line == "END"` is fairly easy to do. Of course, you would need to "waste typing" and declare `line` as `std::string` and use `if (std::getline(std::cin, line)) { ... }` to read it (BTW, you **always** need to check after reading that it was successful; you can give it try and type Ctrl-D or Ctrl-Z at the start of a line to see what happens otherwise).

Comment: You misunderstand about `std::`, and failing to indent your code is discourteous to us.

Comment: I'm unsure of what strcmp is. I'm very new to C++ programming so i don't know all the different functions and methods of doing things.

Comment: You don't have a textbook for your C++ class?

Comment: @Beta: I absolutely agree: good indentation helps understanding the code! Actually, I find it hard to read my own code without indentation, let alone other people's code. Once code gets properly indented it is easy to spot certain errors just based on the structure. Of course, that wouldn't apply to a beginner...

Comment: If you are not willing to type, I suggest a change in career or classes.

Comment: Regarding the typing, the std:: may be required for certain things, but for what I'm doing and cin, cout, endl, they really don't need it, so why write it? I may be ignorant with it, but as far as my class goes, std:: isn't required for our code to function. If someone would like to fill me in on why it would be needed for cin, cout, endl, I'm all ears (or eyes in this case). I understand for something like std::string IS different, but like i said, it isn't what i require right now. I'm also willing to type, but only if it's necessary for something to function properly.

Comment: @Prstorero You are already using `std::` since it's the namespace that `cin` and `cout` are in.  The reason you're not having to type `std::cin` and `std::cout` is because somewhere in your code there is a `using namespace std;`.  The reason folks are using `std` in there comments are to be concise.  Also we don't expect you to indent your own code, if that is how you code so be it.  **BUT**, please take sometime next time when you post a question to properly indent it for others.  They are volunteering time to help answer your questions.  With that said, please mark an answer and good luck

Comment: I do indent my code, sometimes i just do it at the end, it's just how i am, but i will do it before posting next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that will terminate the while loop if "END" is entered.  Create a helper method to do the parsing for `END`.  Note this is very specific to the problem and not very reusable.  It also is more difficult to maintain unlike Beta's solution, but you don't need to worry about maintenance until you start writing bigger programs.

```
bool Terminate(char* string, int len)
{
    bool retval = false;
    char* c = string;

    if( 3 == len )  // "END\0"
    {
        if('E' == string[0])  
        {
            if('N' == string [1]) 
            {
                if('D' == string[2])
                {
                    retval = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return retval;
}
```

Then use it after `int len=strlen(string);` like so:

```
if(Terminate(string, len))
{
    break;  // Exit while loop
}
```

Make sure you declare `Terminate` before your main function

Comment: `strlen("END")` == 3, not 4.

Comment: This worked perfectly for what i needed. I ran the program through its paces and it correctly identifies a palindrome and exits when and only end END is entered. The nice thing is i already understand how this works for an if statement, so i should be all set :) I appreciate the help.

Comment: Your solution assumes uppercase only.  A more robust solution would be to convert the string to all uppercase before comparing.

Comment: @Thomas, converting all to uppercase would go against what my assignment requires. If all lowercase "end" is typed, it's supposed to continue on, but exit if all uppercase END is typed. So if everything was converted to all uppercase, it would defeat the purpose, but i do see where you were going with it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this enough of a hint?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  char A[] = "END";
  char B[10];

  std::cin >> B;

  std::cout << strcmp(A,B) << std::endl;

  return(0);
}
```

Comment: FYI, this has buffer overflow potential.  I recommend `std::cin.get()`, as you can limit the number of characters.